# Do I have to use the name args in public static void main(String args[])

Tags: java, class, object

I am new to Java and I'm learning it. I have a question regarding the statement

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

I understand all of it what it means. My question is regarding the `String args[]` part.

`String args[]` declares a parameter for method `main()` named `args` which is an array of instances of the class `String`.

So can I write anything in place of `args[]`? Like `String pqrs[]` or `String abc[]` or do I have to use `args[]` as a keyword?

I'm just curious to know how this works?

Comment: As always; the best wasy is to try it. But yes `args` is just a convention. You can call it whatever you want

Comment: Yes. It is just a variable name. You can use any name in place of "args"

Comment: And conventionally, it would be `String[] args` as well. Putting the `[]` at the end of the variable name is an abomination :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I really don't know why java even allows that. Its like putting half of the class name at the end of the variable *for no reason*

Comment: @RichardTingle: Familiarity for C/C++ developers, back when Java was very new. Unfortunate short-sightedness, IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using args is just a convention, all of the following would be fine and compile:

```
public static void main(String args[])

public static void main(String abc[])

public static void main(String anythingElse[])
```

However; there is annother (arguably more important) convention you are ignoring that will trip you up down the road.

Its usually

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Doing it the other way round will work, but is confusing because the general assumption is

```
TypeDefinition variableName
```

What is the type, is it a `String`? No, no it is not, its an **array** of strings, which we represent by `String[]`. Is the variable name args[]. No its just `args`

Comment: so by this convention is

(String[] abc, xyz) same as (String abc[], xyz[]) ?

Comment: @user3640307 Yes, and the first one is the correct way to write it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the name to the one you want, because, at the end, the args name is just a convention.

The signature of the method public static void main, has an argument which is String[], and the name of the variable is up to you.

You can have either:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

Or

```
public static void main(String arguments[])
```

Even this:

```
public static void main(String iAmAnArray[])
```

What you cannot have is something like this:

```
public static void main(List<String> iAmAList)
```

Because List is not part of the signature of the method main.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer yes. I just tried it.
args[] is an array. So like most objects declared in a java application you have the freedom to name them. 
Example

```
int i = 4;
```

I could change the "i" to "j" or "k" and it would still perform the same function.
I hope this clears that up for you.